# How to make two dropdowns work simultaneously in a winform?

Tags: winforms

I have 2 dropdown lists in a windows form. First - ProjectName and Second - PartName. When i choose the projectname  projectname_selectedIndexChanged is called and it displays the corresponding parts in that project. but when i choose the part no and set the selected item in projectname to that of the selected part, projectname_selectedIndexChanged  sub is triggered again. What is a better way to go about this task?

Comment: "*but when i choose the part no and set the selected item in projectname to that of the selected part*" Why would you do that? According to the first rule, all the parts should be from the selected project.

Comment: If the user knows the part no. but not the project , he can choose the part no. and project no. will be automatically displayed .

Comment: If you don't want the first box's event to fire again, then replace it with `SelectionChangeCommitted` instead.

Comment: That just got my job done. Thank you!